# Requesting for voice call in mobile app using PHP via elastix server

Tags: php, mysql, xml, post, curl

Am using elastix server for voice call functionality in mobile application, in this I can able to store value(extension data) in asterisk database and also able to view data's in elastix page through the PHP code. When am calling via extension number am receiving "service not available".

How can I solve this issue or else can you tell me how to store the extension data in elastix server using API?